# Silex Payum error : Request Capture{model: Identity} is not supported

Tags: php, paypal, silex, payum

I'm currently using Silex (lastest stable) to make a website where I need to implement a payment system. So I've tried to install Payum (lastest stable), everything worked until I call the prepare page, which redirects me to Payum capture's page (/payment/capture/`hash of the request`) and I get this error :

```
Request Capture{model: Identity} is not supported.
```

For the installation, i've followed the official guide : http://payum.org/doc/1.0/PayumSilexProvider/get-it-started

I've also tried all others versions of Payum with no success.

Here is the trace of the error :

```
in RequestNotSupportedException.php line 29
at RequestNotSupportedException::create(object(Capture)) in Gateway.php line 99
at Gateway->execute(object(Capture)) in ExecuteSameRequestWithModelDetailsAction.php line 32
at ExecuteSameRequestWithModelDetailsAction->execute(object(Capture)) in Gateway.php line 107
at Gateway->execute(object(Capture)) in CaptureController.php line 20
at CaptureController->doAction(object(Request))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(CaptureController), 'doAction'), array(object(Request))) in HttpKernel.php line 147
at HttpKernel->handleRaw(object(Request), '1') in HttpKernel.php line 68
at HttpKernel->handle(object(Request), '1', true) in Application.php line 586
at Application->handle(object(Request)) in Application.php line 563
at Application->run() in app_dev.php line 12
```

If someone could help me, it would make my day ! :)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I've found the answer thank's github and Payum Silex creator @makasim :) 
https://github.com/Payum/Payum/issues/423#issuecomment-150948591

Just add this :

```
<?php
$gateways['paypal_ec']->addExtension(new StorageExtension(
    new FilesystemStorage(__DIR__.'/cache/payum', 'Payum\Core\Model\Payment')
));
```

In gateways registering !